# NGINX/Apache does not respond to requests behind NAT

Tags: nginx, centos, iptables, firewall, web-server

*Warning*: I am a newbie to NGINX. I used apache2 but on CentOS I am not used to the way it is set up and also I want to try NGINX since its newer and more modern.

***Edit*: I have tested also with Apache(httpd) and I had no luck. It seems like the response is not properly forwarded back to the IP/client asking. But when I forward ssh, it works like a charm. With port 80, no luck. I can only access the sites on the local machine. Even machine on the same network cannot access the website.**

I have a simple VM solution running on VMWare. All VMs are running CentOS 7 with selinux disabled.

VM #1 is the Gateway. It's got two NICs, eth0 - internal network, eth1 - wan.
This VM also has iptables set up. I have basic rules that essentialy allow all traffic, but block some unwanted. Also there are NAT rules for forwarding those desired requests for HTTP and HTTPs port to the internal VM like so:

```
*nat
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# HTTP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:80
# HTTPS
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:443
# MySQL
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:3306
# IMAPs
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:993
# SMTP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:25
# SMTPs
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 465 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:465
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:587
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

VM #2 is the Web server. It's running NGINX. It has the default configuration:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

Now, when I do curl 10.10.10.2 from the gateway, I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.10.10.2:80; No route to host
```

but ping works like a charm.

Also when trying the external WAN IP, it says Connection refused.

I am very confused at this point and do not know what I should try and test next. When I add a NAT for ssh, I can access it no problem. But these HTTP/s request do not work. Is it a problem with NGINX? Is there anything else I need to do with the firewall for the NGINX server to be able to respond to the requests outside the VM?

Thank you!

Comment: Check your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So, I thought that the firewall was disabled on the web server VM, but it turns out, it in fact wasn't even though I did stop the service. I stopped it one more time, and now it works with no problems.